# How to get strings that contain only capital letters that exists between any character and space

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to extract only uppercase characters  from a string which i tried in php and got the result but I  want get working on javascript. I tried it in Rublar and I am sharing the link below with example.

http://rubular.com/r/zNcSuNY94y

This is the regular expression that i used for getting the output

```
/(\b[A-Z]{2,}\b)/x
```

For example if we enter

```
gdgdg $HHH $Hhh AAAA $%%% $88 $hHH $HH $YY $YUN
```

we must get

```
HHH HH YY YUN
```

as a result

Comment: What does `x` flag stand for?

Comment: x ignore whitespace in regex

Comment: it looks fine to me what is the problem

Comment: @arun i am not getting it working on javascript

Comment: @SunithSaga JavaScript doesn't have `x` flag. Try global `g` flag instead -- it will match *all* capital letters in a string.

Comment: Your linked example works for me?

Comment: i tried that one too ...

Comment: Your link is dead.  Why not post all the relevant code here?

Comment: Please add whats your DESIRED Outcome is, compared to the script you linked.

Comment: @dognose please have a look  i edited the question.

Answer (score 3):

The following will work fine in JavaScript:

```
"$AAA dflkdklfg sdkjfhgdjkfg #JFJJJJ $SSjsfdsd YYYYYY".match(/(\b[A-Z]{2,}\b)/g);
>> ["AAA", "JFJJJJ", "YYYYYY"]
```

Note, that JS doesn't have `x` flag in regex. You should use `g` flag to match *all* occurrences.

Comment: @VisioN THe desired output must be ["AAA", "JFJJJJ"] and not
["AAA", "JFJJJJ", "YYYYYY"]

Answer (score -1):

```
(\${1}[A-Z]{2,}\b)
```

Using the above code will give the right answer